# Setting background image in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I'm trying to set a background image but the JQuery mobile CSS seems to be overriding my CSS, I have tried the following solution but it is still not working.

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('ProjectImages/logoLong.png');
  background-size: cover;
}

.ui-page { 
  background: transparent;
}

.ui-content{
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: You need a more specific selector on `body`

Comment: I've tried it in `.ui-page` as well but it still didn't work, do you have any suggestions to where I should specify the background?

Comment: Are you certain that it's overriding the image, and not that the path is incorrect?

Comment: This only worked for me after BOTH adding background: url('my image.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed !important, and a more specific background: transparent selector. In my case, .ui-body-c (traced through firebug). Didn't need the .ui-page or .ui-content selectors.

Comment: In fact, .ui-content made containers transparent, which I didn't want.

Answer (score 1):

Try [!important](http://www.css-hack.de/CSS+allgemein/!+important) keyword, so your new color/image will prefered

```
background-image: url('ProjectImages/logoLong.png')!important;
background-color: transparent!important;
```

Comment: Maybe your 'ui-page' has a background-color. Check via firebug the visible background-color.